# White rectangle in subscene when creating a label JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, rendering

Whenever I try to add a label to my JavaFX application, which uses a SubScene in which I draw 3D shapes, I get a white rectangle in the SubScene. I don't even have to do anything with the label, it always does it.

Image of stage without the label
[image]

Image of stage with the label
[image]

I have provided some code with the label, although I couldn't find anything wrong with it.

```
package UI;

import Cargo.CargoSpace;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        //Set Initial stage settings
        stage.setTitle("Pentominoes - Group X");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(Settings.pathToTitleBarImage));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        //Main scene of the stage
        HBox scenePane = new HBox();
        scenePane.setPadding(Settings.mainScenePadding);

        //SubScene containing the cargo space
        CargoSubScene cargoSubScene = new CargoSubScene(new CargoSpace(Settings.cargoSpaceDims[0],Settings.cargoSpaceDims[1],Settings.cargoSpaceDims[2], 2));
        scenePane.getChildren().add(cargoSubScene);

        //SubScene containing the selections in the main menu
        GridPane selectionLayout = new GridPane();
        scenePane.getChildren().add(selectionLayout);

        Label title = new Label("Pentominoes Phase 3");
        selectionLayout.add(title, 0, 0);

        //Adding main scene to the stage
        Scene cargoScene = new Scene(scenePane, Settings.mainSceneSize[0], Settings.mainSceneSize[1]);
        stage.setScene(cargoScene);

        //Displaying the stage
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: Please mark the chosen solution as useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by putting the 2D elements and the 3D ones in a seperate group and than adding both these groups to a super group.